# Redis writes are slower

Tags: caching, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I have a 6 Redis cluster instances running in 2 virtual machines(3 master and 3 slaves). I am trying to load up all my keys every night, which is about .5 billion keys to 1 billion keys. the web application performs calculations and loads these values every night. My fetch is way faster where as writing takes long time. Its taking b/w 6 - 10 seconds to update 10000 keys. I am afraid that nightly load will not finish on time for the users logging in the morning.

below is my cluster config.

cluster-enabled yes

cluster-config-file nodes.conf

cluster-node-timeout 5000

cluster-slave-validity-factor 1

logfile redis.log

loglevel notice

slowlog-log-slower-than 10000

slowlog-max-len 64

latency-monitor-threshold 100

maxmemory 2048mb

maxmemory-policy volatile-ttl

slave-read-only yes

save 900 1

save 300 10

save 60 10000

stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb

appendonly no
daemonize yes

Answer (score 0):

The reason that writing is very slow is probably related to how your Redis persistence is configured. With the current settings Redis will create a snapshot of your dataset every minute. I'd try to test the same import on a test cluster without the "save Y X" config lines and compare it.

Answer (score 0):

I used pipelined commands, which helped to improve the performance way better. pasted my code below to handle 10000 commands in one single execution.

```
private void saveMulti(Map<String, String> cacheableMap){   this.redisResultTemplate.executePipelined(new RedisCallback<Object>(){
    @Override
    public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection)
            throws DataAccessException {
         StringRedisConnection stringRedisConn = 
                         (StringRedisConnection)connection;
        for(String key: cacheableMap.keySet()){     
            stringRedisConn.set(key, cacheableMap.get(key));
        }
    return null;
      }
   });
}
```